# How to save multiple models by using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

How to save multiple SVM models by using python

I am trying to save multiple model to save in a path by taking name from list by using for loop range.

My model is working fine but while trying to save each in unique name getting error.

```
city_id = ['1', '2', '18', '19', '21', '23', '26', '27', '28', '32', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41',
       '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '49', '50', '51', '58', '65', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71']


for i in range(len(city_id)):

    joblib.dump(model, 'D:/Model/model_Predict_Locality_predictor_'+ str(city_id[i]) +'.pkl', compress=1)
```

but getting `out of range error` I have check range also but both range are same.

**Error**

`1
Model Pipeline Created Successfully...
Data fitted Successfully...
Data Predicted Successfully...
Accuracy: 0.9908892595919415
list index out of range
2
Model Pipeline Created Successfully...
Data fitted Successfully...
Data Predicted Successfully...
Accuracy: 0.9790685504971219
list index out of range`

After the accuracy, getting error as above.

Please suggest

Comment: may be you have to loop through the city_id itself instead of 0 to len(city_id)

Comment: if it is only related to out of range at str(city_id[i]) it's working fine.

Comment: How does the model is indexed?

Comment: Please provide a minimal yet executable example. Also you may want to state the complete error message since its probably not `city_id[i]` which causes trouble.

Comment: Can you post the complete error? May be you are getting the error for model

Comment: Is there slightly more code that leading to this error? e.g. Does `model` change in the loop? You could simplify the `for` to iterate over the list directly, and it already contains strings, so I don't see why you need the `str` call. I can't see how this code gives that error.

Comment: Dear All, I have posted full code and error please suggest

Comment: @AILearning, I have posted error. please check

Comment: But the code doesn't show where you calculate the `accuracy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `i` as the index variable for both `for` loops. Correct that and then try!

Comment: I have correct the looping variable with 'c' in the second 'for' loop

Comment: ohh, got it., Thanks

Comment: Kindly accept the answer, if it solved your problem. Thanks